# Why if statement didn't work in react navigation when AsyncStorage is null

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to navigate sign in screen when async storage is null. But always it navigate to home screen. I used function to check if async storage is null or not. But it doesn't work correctly. I was clear app storage in phone settings and run my app. But it always navigating to home screen. Please help me to identify my mistake.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {Home} from './Home';
import {Chat} from './Chat';
import {SignIn} from './SignIn';
import {SignUp} from './SignUp';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App(){
  async function checkUser() {  
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    return user;
  } 
 
    const ui = (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={checkUser!==null?"Home":"Sign In"}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Sign In" component={SignIn} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Sign Up" component={SignUp}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
    return ui;

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not checking the response of a function but you are checking if `checkUser` (which happens to be a function) `!== null`.

This is always `false` because `checkUser` is defined (thus not null)

edit:
Because you are dependent on an `async` method to validate which route you should display first, you could write a separate helper component

```
const InitalStateSetter = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then(user => {
      if(user) {
       navigation.replace("Home")
       return
      }
      
      navigation.replace("Sign In")
    }
  }, [navigation])

  return null
}
```

Which you can use inside of your `NavigationContainer`

```
<NavigationContainer>
   <InitalStateSetter />
   {/* ... rest */}
</NavigationContainer>
```

You can use the `replace` instead of `push` because I assume you do not want the user to navigate back to the void [see replace docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace)